# Frustrating pointer error

Tags: c++

For the life of me, I can't figure out what is going wrong. I know the error is occurring in the function marked displayQueue below, but all the syntax and logic seems correct.

Visual studio is giving me the error: "Unhandled exception at 0x00215A86 in ex11_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDE1." But really, I have no idea what this is referring to...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct QueueNode {
    string data;
    QueueNode *link;
};
typedef QueueNode* QueueNodePtr;


class Queue {
public:
    // Constructors/Destructor.
    Queue();
    Queue(const Queue& aQueue);

    // Accessors.
    bool empty() const;
    void displayQueue ();

    // Mutators.
    void add(string item);
    string remove();    // This should probably be replaced with pop and top - especially for displayQueue... empty() in functions can be replaced with count == 0. Yes, I will do this.

private:
    QueueNodePtr front;     // Points to head of linked-list queue.
    QueueNodePtr back;      // Points to tail of linked-list queue.
    size_t count;
};

int main () {
    Queue myQueue;

    myQueue.add("abc");
    myQueue.add("def");
    myQueue.add("ghi");

    myQueue.displayQueue();     // The error is here somewhere. abc is printed and but nothing else.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Queue::Queue() {
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

Queue::Queue(const Queue& aQueue) {
    front = aQueue.front;
    back = aQueue.back;
    count = aQueue.count;
}

bool Queue::empty() const {
    if (count == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Queue::displayQueue () {
    // There is a problem here somewhere...

    QueueNodePtr here = front;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << here->data << endl;
        here = here->link;      
    }
}

void Queue::add(string item) {
    QueueNodePtr newNode;
    newNode = new QueueNode;

    if (count == 0) {
        // If inserted in an empty queue, back and front point to same element.
        newNode->data = item;
        // newNode->link = NULL;    // Not sure this part is even necessary.
        back = newNode;
        front = back;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, leave front pointer where it's at.
        newNode->data = item;
        newNode->link = back->link;
        back = newNode;
    }
    count ++;
}

string Queue::remove() {
    string returnString;

    if (count == 0) {
        return returnString;
    } else if (count == 1) {
        returnString = front->data;
        front = NULL;
        back = front;
        count--;
        return returnString;
    } else {
        returnString = front->data;
        front = front->link;
        count--;
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

EDIT: If anyone can give me any tips on using the debugger to solve problems like this, or give me a link that might explain this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger?

Comment: Yes? I believe that's where the error message I posted above comes from.

Answer (score 4):

The error is on this line, but for the sake of learning, I won't give the correct version, just a few hints:

```
newNode->link = back->link;
```

At the point where this code is being executed, which node does `back` point to? What does its `link` point to? Whose node's `link` do you need to modify?

As for finding this yourself, you could have used the debugger to figure out which line causes the crash; this would have indicated that something is wrong with a `link` value.

P.S. Your copy constructor doesn't actually copy the linked list; it just creates a new Queue object that points to the same linked list, so if you add an element to the copy, it will show up in the original Queue.

Comment: How would I use the debugger to do this? Right now I'm in the debugger, and Visual Studio is pointing to a line in the file xstring.

Comment: Thank you for the help otherwise though. I figured out what was wrong.

Comment: @featherlight53: Use the Call Stack window to find which line in your own source code called that code.

Answer (score 2):

An access violation at address `0xCDCDCDCD` means that your program loaded a pointer from uninitialized storage and then dereferenced it. Microsoft's debugging allocator uses this pattern for newly allocated uninitialized storage, and in a suitable compilation mode, also for stack locations. If you treat such uninitialized storage as a pointer variable, the pattern is recognizeable in that pointer. Moreover, it is almost certainly an invalid pointer that will trigger an exception. So the benefit is that the use of the invalid pointer is caught quickly, and the pattern tells you that the cause is quite likely uninitialized storage (though this is not 100% conclusive).

For example:

```
struct contains_pointer { char *str; } *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);

strcpy(ptr->str, "abc"); // ptr->str is uninitialized
```

Or:

```
int *pint;
*pint = 0;  // pint is uninitialized
```

To have the compiler and library overwrite uninitialized storage with a pattern like CDCDCD... can be quite helpful. You should pinpoint the location of the crash with the debugger, and then work backward from there: where did the pointer value originate and why wasn't it initialized.

(A bad pointer to the address CDCDCDCD could result in other ways: sheer fluke (unlikely) or a use-after-free bug: the program frees some memory but continues to keep a pointer to it, without using it for a while. The memory is then re-allocated to some other part of the program, and marked uninitialized, and by chance, the original user of the pointer makes a use of it, loading a pointer value from the memory. At that moment, a CDCDCDCD pointer results, so it looks like a use-before-init bug, when in fact it's a use-after-free bug.   Debugging based on "memory poisoning" patterns is not accurate!)